# "until just recently I have been A’s immediate friend for 3 months" sounds correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Until just recently I have been A’s immediate friend and classmate for 3 months.

Is this same as saying "recently I have got to be acquainted with A as a classmate"

Comment: No, it makes no sense. "Until" implies a situation that has ended.

Comment: It sounds as though you have been A's friend for 3 months, but have recently quarrelled with them! Also, _immediate friend_ is not idiomatic.

Comment: "immediate" can in some contexts mean "near, close" (as in *your **immediate** family*), but we don't use it for ***close friends***.

Comment: The example utterance isn't "the same" as saying *anything* - it's simply ***invalid***. Either *I **have been** her close friend for 3 months* (and still am) OR *Until recently I **was** her close friend* (but not any more). If you want to convey the duration *and* the recency of the "no longer" aspect you probably need some pretty radical restructuring - and I can't see any easy way to do this without explicitly saying that ***we fell out recently*** (the friendship breakdown is implied just by the word ***until***, but that simply doesn't work once you include ***for 3 months***).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, neither sentence is good English.

First, the present perfect does not seem to be warranted in either sentence. The use of the present perfect in some languages largely overlaps the use of the simple past in English, but the usage of the present perfect in English has no equivalent in any of the other languages I know.

> Until recently, I was ...

and

> I have been ... for three months

are both correct, but mean different things. So your first sentence does not make any sense.

Second, the first sentence contains information, namely “for three months” that is not present in the second so the two sentences cannot possibly have the same meaning.

Moreover, “friend” and “acquaintance” have somewhat different meanings. And if “immediate friend” is supposed to mean “close friend,” then “acquainted with” is not correct at all.

Third, as a result of the first two points, it is not clear what either sentence really means. My best **GUESS** is

> I became [acquainted/friendly] with A when we took the same class three months ago.

Choose “acquainted” or “friendly” depending on your intended meaning.